# Performance differences between EXT4 and XFS on kernel 4.15.0-76

Tags: performance, database-performance

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Kernel version: 4.15.0-76-generic
Storage type: RAID10 (4 x SSD)

Question: is it a bug for this version of kernel? EXT4 run a lot slower when we perform same SQL insert test; XFS respond a lot healthier at 2K INSERT + 2K UPDATE while EXT4 only have 59 for both.

IOSTAT also showing EXT4 was at 98.4% utilization.

[image]

[image]

---

Another test: everything is the same, upgraded kernel to 5.6.0-050600-generic

EXT4:
[image]

XFS:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the underlying block devices, they are very different. ext4 labored really hard: 377 w/s, 2.94 ms wait, 98
%util. xfs had no problems: 6277 w/s, 0.07 ms wait, 42 %util.

Milliseconds versus microseconds block device latency is difficult to explain with the file system. ext4 is not inherently 40x slower. Hundreds of IOPS and couple ms latency is as if on spindles and not SSD. Although, it could be a broken or poorly tuned SSD.

Reformat the well-performing xfs device (sda?) with ext4. Document file system creation commands and mount options. Re-run the test. That will be a more fair comparison, only changing one variable: the file system type.

Comment: Updated question after upgrade kernel, EXT4 performance become normal

Comment: ... or it is file system related after all. I have no idea what in the kernel had such a drastic change.  Take your pick, XFS is a fine file system, or you can get a newer kernel if that performs better.

Comment: we already decided to move to newer kernel, but I want to see if anyone know the actual reason

Comment: There are many more variables to examine, kernels to bisect, and more profiling to try. For example, can it be reproduced with just a fio storage test? Is it MySQL in particular, or any write heavy DBMS? Consider opening an issue with your OS support, and see if you can get a performance engineer to study your environment in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I found the potential answer for this,

"cat /sys/block/{block device}/queue/scheduler" indicates the system is using "cfq", which is a problem when we have SSD/NVMe drives. Change it to "deadline" or "noop" solve this issue, detail explanation please refer to Ubuntu wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Reference/IOSchedulers

CFQ scheduler already gone is the latest stable kernel, but this is Ubuntu 18 which is running older version of kernel, change IO scheduler by hand solve this.